# MFC keep line draw after resizing

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to create a simple Paint application using `MFC`. So everything working good and as expected. I have just one issue with resising, in fact when i re-size my window or minimizing it everything disappear and I got blank page. I found that this's caused by the OnDraw function, but I can't find how to deal with that issue.

Comment: I suspect that you are painting your window outside of OnDraw(), is that right? Then the answer is - don't do it.

Comment: Yeah i draw lines and others shapes outside the OnDraw() because I need to use the events OnLButtonUp, OnMouseMove...

Comment: You need to store the shapes you want to render (for example in your mouse message handlers), and always render those shapes in your `WM_PAINT` message handler. Assuming you have `CS_HREDRAW`/`VS_VREDRAW` window class styles, everything else will just work.

Comment: And how to store those shapes

Comment: @MoezRebai: "And how to store those shapes", hard to answer that question in 2 or 3 sentences. There is an example called "scribble" which does exactly what you want, simply google "mfc scribble".

Comment: Review the DRAWCLI example drawing program in the MSDN MFC samples.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I can't find a C++/MFC example for the scribble sample it's on c++/clr

Comment: @MoezRebai 30 seconds google search: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92y4h944(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I Know but there's now downloadable file

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the OnDraw function is to recreate the drawing after the window has been resized/uncovered/unminimized. Your OnDraw function must be able to draw everything at any time. So the event handlers like OnLButtonUp should set variables that can be used by OnDraw. Then the event handlers can call Invalidate to cause a new OnDraw.

Comment: so if I understand you for the mouse mouve event I must store all the points and then recreate the shape at the on draw function